# Lots of new member SPAM

Tags: spam

I'm working on a site that is online in a dev environment. I'm getting tons of new member spam. I have snaptcha installed and it's set to High and it doesn't seem to be helping. Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since it is your dev environment the easiest way to prevent registrations is to turn them off via Members > Preferences.

While that doesn't really address the root of the issue it is effective. If you want to help combat the spam while still allowing member registrations you can do a couple of things.

- Change the member profile trigger word to something other then "member". You can do this by either navigating to Members > Preferences > Profile Trigger Word. The option that I use and that the FocusLab Master Config file uses it just to set a random string each page load by adding something along the lines of below to the config.php file

  // randomize the member profile trigger word because we'll never need it 
  $config['profile_trigger']          = rand(0,time());
- Use a different Spam service/add-on. I have never used Snaptcha so I have no experience with it but I have used [Low NoSpam](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-nospam) for as long as I can remember and have only had a very limited number of spam registrations come in during that time.

Comment: Thank you, Justin. Great advice here! I have Low's extension installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider building invitations-based system.

[Invitations add-on for ExpressionEngine](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/invitations) will allow site visitors request invitations; and new signups will only be accepted from people who have valid invitation code.